# symfony. bundle. Как растащить роуты по бандлам?

Tags: php, symfony, роутер, bundles

Необходимо перенести мои роуты по бандлам, но стоит вопрос - как?
Из документации на сайте Симфони не очень очевиден ответ для моего случая.
 Файл с роутами: `routes.yaml`

```
create-user:
path: /user
controller: App\Controller\CreateUserController::createAction 

get-auth:
path: /auth
```

Подключение бандлов `bundles.php`

```
<?php

return [
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
App\Portmone\Api\PortmoneBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для 4 версии с аннотациями:

config/routes/annotations.yaml:

```
bundle1:
    resource: ../../src/Bundle1/Controllers
    type: annotation
bundle2:
    resource: ../../src/Bundle2/Controllers
    type: annotation
```

В контроллерах:
src/Bundle1/Controllers/FirstController.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class FirstController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * @Route("/first")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }
}
```

src/Bundle2/Controllers/SecondController.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SecondController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * @Route("/second")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }
}
```

И далее можете расписывать роуты уже непосредственно в контроллерах своих бандлов без дополнительных конфигов

Если просто нужно разнести конфиги, то в config/routes создайте по отдельному файлу .yaml для каждого бандла и перенесите в отдельные файлы свои роуты

Comment: Да, именно оно. Спасибо!